# WiX toolset: Custom Actions that require .NET 4.5

Tags: c#, wix, advanced-installer

I am writing custom actions for Advanced Installer using the WiX toolset.

The custom action project is .NET framework 4 by default, but I would like to use dependencies that are only compatible to .NET 4.5.

My installer is set to require .NET 4.5.2, so it is safe to assume that when the custom actions are executed, .NET 4.5.2 or higher is available.

Can I safely increase the .NET version, or will this break the installer?

Comment: What's your output? A MSI file? Or a bootstrapper (.exe)?

Comment: @MortenFrederiksen LZMA compressed exe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can increase the .NET version required. As long as you have set the launch condition in your Advanced Installer project for that version of .NET the MSI will not run if that version of .NET or a higher one is not found on the machine.

If you have multiple builds in your project, make sure the launch condition is set for all.